# why does 400 status code result always entercatch block execution with axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have a contact me form in my frontend with **three fields -> name, email, message.** which are being passed to backend using axis

> if the user doesn't enter any of the one value, it should show  "please fill all the details" which is coming from backend. But here in my case in browser console.log i am seeing this error

```
POST https:/api-endpoint/contactMe 400

try-catch block catch error:

    Error: Request failed with status code 400
        at createError (createError.js:16:1)
        at settle (settle.js:17:1)
        at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62:1)
```

**If all the fields are entered it results in successful message from backend which is "thank you for contacting jatin" - this works perfectly well**

Why 200 status code msg from backend is working and why 400 status code msg from backend results in error? Is this an issue with axios that for 400 or error status code it will raise exception?

Here is my react code

```
const handleName = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleEmail = (e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleMessage = (e) => {
    setMessage(e.target.value);
  };
  const submitForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      let data = {
        name,
        email,
        message,
      };
      setBool(true);
      console.log(data);
      const res = await axios.post(
        'https:/api-endpoint/contactMe',
        data
      );
      console.log(res);
      if (name.length === 0 || email.length === 0 || message.length === 0) {
        console.log('hihi');
        setBanner(res.data.msg);
        toast.error(res.data.msg);
        setBool(false);
      } else if (res.status === 200) {
        setBanner(res.data.msg);
        toast.success(res.data.msg);
        setBool(false);

        setName('');
        setEmail('');
        setMessage('');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

my backend route

```
app.post('/contactMe', async (req, res, next) => {
  const data = req.body;
  if (
    data.name.length < 1 ||
    data.email.length < 1 ||
    data.message.length < 1
  ) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Please fill all the fields' });
  }

  const params = {
    Destination: {
      ToAddresses: ['reciever@gmail.com'],
    },
    Message: {
      Body: {
        Text: { Data: `${data.message}` },
      },

      Subject: {
        Data: `Hiring interest from "${data.name}" : "${data.email}"`,
      },
    },
    Source: 'sender@gmail.com',
  };
  try {
    const data = await ses.sendEmail(params).promise();
    console.log(data);
    return res.status(200).json({ msg: 'Thank you for contacting Jatin!!!' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Service Unavailable' });
  }
});
```

Comment: I think that's the default behavior with axios; status codes out of the 2xx range are errors.

Comment: @Pointy if thats the case dealing it within catch block would be a good idea? or do you have any ideas?

Comment: Well it's one idea; it's your own server-side code that's responding with status code 400 when one or more parameters are missing. You could report the errors in a different way perhaps.

Comment: @thank you Pointy Playing with status code on server-side is a clever idea, you can try posting it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this approach might help you?

```js
const handleName = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleEmail = (e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleMessage = (e) => {
    setMessage(e.target.value);
  };
  const submitForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
      let data = {
        name,
        email,
        message,
      };
      setBool(true);
      console.log(data);
      const res = await axios.post(
        'https:/api-endpoint/contactMe',
        data
      ).then(res => { // Response handler
        console.log(res);
        setBanner(res.data.msg);
        toast.success(res.data.msg);
        setBool(false);

        setName('');
        setEmail('');
        setMessage('');
      }).catch(error => { // Error handler
        console.log(error);
        setBanner(error.response.data.msg);
        toast.error(error.response.data.msg);
        setBool(false);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

Even though @Simon's solution did worked for me

> As per comments, axios default behavious to raise error for status codes other than 2xx.

So a clever way would be to just change status code on server side.

changing **400 with 200** and `200 with 201` also helped me.